# 'Prevaricate' as a synonym for 'vacillate'

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

There's a lot of motivation here.  It boils down to a two-part question:  is the usage of 'prevarication' as a synonym for 'vacillation' common, acceptable, and/or preferable; and is there any reason that it might crop up particularly often in the history of Austria and Germany?

I am currently reading Max Hastings's [Catastrophe 1914](https://books.google.com/books?id=bwDONAEACAAJ), which I am very much enjoying, except for this usage, which jars me.  Some example quotes:

> Russia's prevarications about the exact pattern of its mobilisation were almost certainly irrelevant to the European outcome.
>
> But if German policy had vacillated earlier in July, now the march to war had attained its own momentum.  In Berlin on the 29th, Falkenhayn sought to force the pace: he declared that the time for prevarication was over ….
>
> Gallieni fumed at the prevarications of bureaucrats, who seemed incapable of adjusting from the tempo of peace to that of extreme national peril ….

Unfortunately, this book isn't previewed on Google Books, so you'll have to take my word that the surroundings make it clear that 'prevarication' here is *not* meant to refer to deception, but rather to what I think of as vacillation.  Note particularly the second quote, where 'vacillation' is even *used* in the previous sentence, to describe the behaviour the time for which was over.  For an example sentence with more context, and also to note that this usage is not peculiar to Hastings, see https://books.google.com/books?id=9Y0osRlmQcIC&pg=PP47#q=prevaricate:

> Some officials and politicians thought that Hitler would continue to prevaricate ….

(Here you really probably will want to check the context to verify that it is not a reference to prevarication as deception, in which Hitler certainly engaged wantonly.)

To my shock, when I went to the OED to back up my distaste with this usage, I found it saying very much the contrary (http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/151057#eid112455102):

> 3b. To behave evasively or indecisively so as to delay action; to procrastinate. Now the usual sense.

However, a hallway survey of several colleagues produced the uniform reaction "no, that's not what it means at all!"; *and* I noticed that the second quote is clearly about Nazism, while the first refers to—I don't know what, but clearly some conflict involving Austria.  So, I am back to the question at the beginning:  is this usage really 'usual', and is there any reason that it seems to crop up so often in the history of Austria and Germany?

Comment: I really do not understand your issue; prevaricate is to lie and vacillate is to be indecisive. The two terms are not "related". As for historical interpretation, I am no historian but I do not understand what your distaste is about: Russia was lying (prevaricating about its positions); Germany was vacillating - hadn't decided definitively to invade or not, I assume.

Comment: Prevarication and vacillation are not synonymous.

Comment: @Lambie, my issue is that your first sentence ("prevaricate is to lie and vacillate is to be indecisive") accords with my understanding, but not with the OED definition or the quoted sentences.  In all of them, prevarication refers not to deception, but to indecision.  (I agree that the lack of context makes the 'deception' interpretation plausible, but reading the surrounding text—which it seems to exceed fair use to quote—makes it clear that that is not what is meant.)

Comment: I am sure that prevarication as indecision is not the first OED meaning for the word.....

Comment: @Lambie, it is not the first meaning (in fact it is (3b), as indicated).  However, the OED certainly does say that the definition I have quoted is "now the usual sense".  (You can check the link if you doubt it—as I do, despite having checked and quoted it myself!)

Comment: It doesn't really matter. The author's intended meaning is not 3b. It is to contrast prevarication (lying by deception) with vacillation (being indecisive. It's seems completely obvious to me...You are saying the words are "synonymous" and I am saying they are not at all synonymous.

Comment: @Lambie, I believe that the context reveals that "It is to contrast prevarication (lying by deception) with vacillation (being indecisive)" is not true.  It may be useful to check the context in Google Books of the last quote (from Overy, not Hastings), where it is very clear that the reference is to Hitler's indecision, not to his (ample) practice of deception.

Comment: @Lambie, also, to be clear, I am not claiming that the words are synonymous—I think that they are not.  However, the quoted sentences, and (to a lesser extent) the OED definition that I quote, seems to *suggest* that they are.

Comment: This is impossible. We're going round and round.   You need to worry less about the OED and more about the author's point of view. To me, the author's point of view is very clear: Russia was prevaricating about its mobilisation (basically lying) while Germany was vacillating (being indecisive about its policy). Very straightforward. The text seems to be some unidentifiable anxiety for you  that I cannot grasp. ..

Comment: I don't see the OED (3b) as pure *indecision*, it was evasive or indicisive with a desired outcome of delay.  I might *vacillate* only because I'm torn about the result.   So I might *vacillate* to *prevaricate*, but it wouldn't work the other way around.  But this equine is necrodestined.

Comment: See also [equivocate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20371/is-equivocate-a-euphemism-for-lie-or-can-it-not-be-about-lying)

Comment: @SteveRacer, your point is good that the definition that I quote does not seem quite to declare 'prevaricate' and 'vacillate' synonyms—that was just my gloss.  However, it does seem to omit what I think of as a crucial ingredient of prevarication, which is an intent to *deceive*.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first part of your question:

> is the usage of 'prevarication' as a synonym for 'vacillation' common,
>   acceptable, and/or preferable?

The two words are *not* synonymous, so to use them as synonyms is very *un*common, generally *un*acceptable and certainly *not* preferable.

> **Prevaricate** -- [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prevaricate)
>   Speak or act in an evasive way:
>   *'he seemed to prevaricate when journalists asked pointed questions'
>
> [examples of "prevarication":]
>   *'Even so, he has continued his policy of deception and prevarication.'*
>   *'Now we are fed big pills of outright lies, prevarication, and deception.'*
>   *'I met people who had endured 12 hours of mis-information and prevarication before they boarded a plane.'*

Compare with:

> **Vacillation** -- [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vacillation)
>   The inability to decide between different opinions or actions; indecision:
>   *'the First Minister’s vacillation over the affair'*

Regarding the second part of your question:

> is there any reason that it might crop up particularly often in the
>   history of Austria and Germany?

It's not certain that these words in the examples you've provided mean anything other than as defined, so this part of your question can't be answered. "Prevarication" can certainly be used as a means of delaying a decision or action, but that's a deliberate act, and not quite the same as the *inability* that "vacillation" indicates. The ODO entry for "procrastinate" cited above also notes that:

> The verbs **prevaricate** and **procrastinate** have similar but not
>   identical meanings. **Prevaricate** means ‘act or speak in an evasive
>   way’, as in he **prevaricated** at the mention of money.
>   **Procrastinate**, on the other hand, means ‘put off doing something’, as in the Western powers will **procrastinate** until it is too late.
>   The meanings are closely related—if someone prevaricates they often
>   also procrastinate—and this can give rise to confusion in use.

Comment: I am curious about the ODO entry.  I see from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-are-the-main-differences-between-the-oed-and-odo that "The … Oxford Dictionaries focuses on current English …. The OED … forms a record of all the core words and meanings in English … including many obsolete and historical terms"; but definition (3b) that I quote, which explicitly says that it is *now* the usual sense, seems in direct contradiction to the ODO definition you quote.  I'm not sure what to make of that (although it does agree with my own sense of the meanings).

Comment: For "It's not certain that these words in the examples you've provided mean anything other than as defined", I agree that, with the limited context available, it is plausible to read them in the way that you describe.  However, focussing for example on the second quote (about Germany), I think that it is implausible to read a call for an end to *prevarication* as a response to *vacillation* if the author means different things by the two words.  (It seems implausible that one of Germany's own leaders would declare that Germany should stop "speak[ing] or act[ing] in an evasive way"!) (cont'd)

Comment: The rest of that sentence says "the time for prevarication was over; Germany could no longer wait for Russia to move, but must mobilise."  It seems to me that the only plausible reading of this is that it is the *waiting* or indecision, not the *lying*, that must stop.

Comment: @LSpice: Your points are all reasonable, but I think we need to differentiate between what the *words* mean, and what the *author* meant. Have you considered that the author of the sentence may simply have used "prevaricate" incorrectly, and may really have meant "procrastinate"?

Comment: That is a very good point, that I hadn't really considered.  However, it occurs 3 times in this book (so is at least not an isolated error), 1ce in Overy's book, and (I am convinced though I cannot find the specific source) at least 1ce in some other book I have read; so it seems that, if this is an error, then it is at least a persistent one.